# anchor tag not working on laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I wont to make direct page with anchor tag in blade template engine, but its not work.

> _sidebar.blade.php

```
<li class="active treeview">
      <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Menu Utama</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview">
      <a href="{{ url('data_jamaah') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        <span>Data Jamaah</span>
      </a>
```

> routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
Route::get('data_jamaah', 'PagesController@getJamaah');
```

> PagesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Inbox;

class PagesController extends Controller
 {
   public function getIndex() {
      return view('pages.index');
     }

    public function getJamaah() {
        return view('pages.data_jamaah');
   }

 }
```

The problem is When i click a  nothing to happen, thanks for your help

Edit:

> This is main.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   @include('partials._head')
   @yield('stylesheets')
</head>

  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
   <div class="wrapper">
      @include('partials._nav')
      @include('partials._sidebar')
      @yield('content')
    <footer class="main-footer">
        @include('partials._footer')
    </footer> 
</div>
@include('partials._javascript')
@yield('javascripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Can you show the generated html?

Comment: @RomnickSusa when i click on the button, nothing to happen

Comment: Where is your button? you mean `<a>` tags? which one?

Comment: @Jerodev i think this i enough

Comment: @MisaGH yes i mean a <a> tags

Comment: You code looks right. But we don't know where the _sidebar is included or the exact errors. Did you see your browser console?

Comment: @MisaGH this is main.blade.php https://pastebin.com/nwiUEL2a

Comment: When you click on the link, your address bar would be changed? and the page is empty or white or what? please explain the error more.

Comment: @MisaGH when i click on <a> the address bar nothing to change, still on localhost:8000

Comment: @AzzarioRazy And when you show your source code on your browser, what does your anchor looks like ?

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur its show <li class="treeview">
          <a href="http://localhost:8000/data_jamaah">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span>Data Jamaah</span>
          </a>
        </li>

Comment: This is weird!! please show us the source of page

Comment: what is your .env file?

Comment: @MisaGH https://pastebin.com/yMHL8gdU this is a source page

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur Still not works

Comment: your source seems OK! its very strange. I think you need to explain it more!

Comment: Is there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @MisaGH but when i add some <a> other not in _sidebar. its works :(

Comment: @MisaGH console says error on morris.js, but i think its not take effect on my <a>

Comment: I don't know anymore. hope anyone could help you. It is good to take a screenshot from your page if anyone wants to know more

Comment: I think its errors on the CSS or HTML Structure maybe?

Comment: @AzzarioRazy I think that i found the solution, look at my answer ;)

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is coming from of how you are using adminLTE Sidebar.

When you specify **treeview** in your class, you will have a dropdown list. And the anchor will be deactivated.

So try something like that :

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
       <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Menu Utama</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="{{ url('data_jamaah') }}">
       <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
       <span>Data Jamaah</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its Solved

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this hope this work for you:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex')->name('home');
Route::get('data_jamaah', 'PagesController@getJamaah')->name('dataJamaah');

<li class="active treeview">
      <a href="{{route('home')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Menu Utama</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview">
      <a href="{{route('dataJamaah')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        <span>Data Jamaah</span>
      </a>
```

Comment: @AzzarioRazy : Are you use any middleware or prefix on route?

Comment: i dont add middleware to my routes

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has it's own helper function to create the routes, which you can see here:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route

Edit:

**You also need to have a name for your routes to work from the helper function.**

On your **routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex', 'as' => 'homepage']);
Route::get('data_jamaah', ['uses' => 'PagesController@getJamaah', 'as' => 'data.jamaah']);
```

You need to change the href from `url()` to `route()`.

Change

**From:**

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}">
```

**To:**

```
<a href="{{ route('homepage') }}">
```

and for other route

**From:**

```
<a href="{{ url('data_jamaah') }}">
```

**To:**

```
<a href="{{ route('data.jamaah') }}">
```

And it will work perfectly fine.

If we specify the name the laravel routes automatically gets the route and renders for you.

Comment: @AzzarioRazy Sorry i had missed the route name which you need to specify the laravel on which route it is heading to.